# convert RMatrix::Column to a NumericVector

Tags: r, rcpp, rcppparallel

How do you convet an `RMatrix::Column` to a `NumericVector` in `RcppParallel`?

e.g.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>

a = RMatrix<double>(4,5,1.0);
RMatrix<double>::Column a0 = a.column(0);
NumericVector b(Rcpp::as<NumericVector>(a0));
```

> error: no matching function for call to 'as'                    NumericVector b(Rcpp::as(a0));

Comment: This is the second poorly researched question by you in three hours.  I put some time into your previous question; I may be less inclined to so again.  Please *do* read the RcppParallel examples more carefully as they show you how this works.

Comment: You'll want to read through the `RcppParallel` website, especially this section: http://rcppcore.github.io/RcppParallel/#safe_accessors  As an aside, why do you want this conversion (i.e. what purpose would converting an `RcppParallel::RMatrix::Column` to an `Rcpp::NumericVector` accomplish for you)?